# Join Tables On Two Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

i've been trying to join to one table but using two different columns. Ok so i've got the following tables:

Users:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| user_id | name                                 |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1       | Bob                                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2       | John                                 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Table2:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| user_one | user_two  | field3                  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1        | 2         | something here          |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Is their any way to join the user's table using both fields. Something like this:

```sql
    SELECT 
     table2.*,
     users.name
    FROM table2
    INNER JOIN users
    ON users.user_id = table2.user_one AND users.user_id = table2.user_two
```

I've tried the above query but it doesn't return anything.

*Edit*
I would want to return something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| user_one_name | user_two_name  | field3        |
--------------------------------------------------
| Bob           | John           | something here|
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What are your desired results?  Perhaps you actually want to join to the `users` table multiple times to get the name for each user in `table2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two joins.  This is often done using `left join` in case one or both user ids do not match:

```
SELECT t2.*, u1.name as user1name, u2.name as user2name
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     users u1
     ON u1.user_id = t2.user_one LEFT JOIN
     users u2
     ON u2.user_id = t2.user_two;
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to get the name of both users in a single row.  Assuming so, then you can `join` to the `users` table multiple times:

```
SELECT 
    table2.*,
    u1.name user1name,
    u2.name user2name
FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.user_id = t2.user_one
    INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.user_id = t2.user_two
```

---

As mentioned in a comment, if it's possible you have user ids in `table2` that do not exist in the `users` table (or you allow `null` values to be stored), you ***can*** use an `outer join` instead to get your desired results.

However, if that is the case, you may have larger issues with your database design.  You shouldn't have `foreign keys` that don't have corresponding `primary keys` unless those are perhaps nullable.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, using INNER JOIN is tad risky.. as no result would be returned if either of the join doesn't find a match.


Based on the example in question, your query won't fetch any results, would it?

Comment: @SethuSabarish -- in the posted data, there are 2 users, id 1 and id 2.  Both exist.  In a decent database design, there would be constraints to ensure you couldn't have missing users.  However, if that is the case, then it's rather trivial to convert to `outer joins`....